# How to enable the use of the Cluster Analysis plugin

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, clustering

I have installed QGIS version 3.28.11. I have also installed the Cluster Analysis plugin (https://github.com/folini96/Cluster-Analysis-plugin).

From the plugin installation window, when I try to activate the checkbox to enable this plugin, a window appears with the following error message:

[image]

According to the error description:

```
Couldn't load plugin 'Cluster-Analysis-plugin-main' due to an error when calling its classFactory() method. 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn'.
```

There seems to be a missing module ('`sklearn`') installation

How can I fix this problem?

**Installation problem scikit_learn**

[image]

Comment: You should raise this as an issue on the plugins issue tracker: https://github.com/folini96/Cluster-Analysis-plugin/issues

Comment: Assuming you followed the installation instructions: https://github.com/folini96/Cluster-Analysis-plugin#install-dependencies

Comment: I have not followed the manual installation suggested in the manual plugin user guide, since I have verified that the QGIS 3.28.11 version automatically incorporates the numpy, scipy, pysal and pandas libraries. It seems that the only missing library is scikit-learn, which seems to be the source of the problem.
In this specific instalation of QGIS 3.28.11 I can't find individual installation instructions for scikit-learn

Comment: scikit_learn is not bundled with the python provided by installing qgis which is why there is a specific installation guide to follow for this plugin.

Comment: Thank you for your confirmation. Now I would need help to install scikit_learn following the instructions in the user guide, I can't get it installed. I am attaching in my question screenshots of the error message I get. Sorry for my lack of knowledge with the Commad line, it is probably a syntax error

Comment: You should still follow the steps in the install instructions for scikit_learn. Step 1.  Open the OSGeo4w Shell 2. Run: py3_env 3. Run: python -m pip install scikit-learn

Comment: @emblematica you tried to run the `python -m pip install sckit-learn` from inside a python interpreter which won't work it needs to be inside the OSGeo4w Shell or use  `"C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.28.11\bin\python-qgis.bat" -m pip install scikit-learn` or `"C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.28.11\bin\python-qgis-ltr.bat" -m pip install scikit-learn` in a regular cmd.exe command prompt